# How to add update-grub to grub boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, live-usb

update-grub is useful for fast re-configuring grub

especially when using multiple hard disks

I need a way to add this functionality to grub menu itself?

Comment: That's not possible at all.

Comment: should be some idea there

Comment: isn't there a way to run a command form the system automaticly/menu item?